# find and replace in Elasticsearch / kibana 5.2

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Is there any way to find and replace the value against particular field of my index with updated value?
In my index, lets say Index name = States_of_India, "State"="Jammu & Kashmir" is populated. I want to replace the '&' sign with "and".
How to do find and replace?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Update by Query API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.2/docs-update-by-query.html), or the [Update API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.2/docs-update.html).

For example, if you want to replace the '&' sign with 'and' in the "State" field values, you can try something like this:

```
POST /index-name/_update_by_query
{
    "script":
    {
        "lang": "painless",
        "inline": "ctx._source.State = ctx._source.State.replace('&', 'and')"
    }
}
```